# How to convert a C-type variadic to C++ style variadic type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function which currently looks like this:

```
void log(uint8_t level, const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    char msg[128];
    int  msg_size = vsnprintf(msg, 128, fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    callback->dosomething(level, msg); // some api
}
```

I want to convert it to,

```
void log(uint8_t level, const char* fmt, Args... args) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    char msg[128];
    int  msg_size = vsnprintf(msg, 128, fmt, va); // do some things similar here with args
    va_end(va);
    callback->dosomething(level, msg); // some api
}
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Your title says "from C++ style to C style" but your question body presents the opposite

Comment: Ted Lyngmo yes it is.

Comment: @kishoredbn `Args...` says that it's not. That's something you'll find in C++ code, not in C code.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo wait! I am confused. ```Args...``` is c++, plain ```... ```is c right?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  my bad, I din't see that. Typo. Thanks for point that out.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Didn't see that. Was a typo. What I am looking for is C to C++ variadic.

Comment: If you want this to actually go through C APIs in the end, it's actually surprisingly difficult to do without breaking `-Wformat` (I've done it, but I only license that GPL3). If you don't care, it's as simple as adding the missing `template` line and calling the ordinary `snprintf`. Alternatively, you could use one of the modern C++-specific format libraries.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't care about i18n and don't have any other reason to rearrange the arguments in the format string, it may be feasible to use `<iostream>`. But everybody hates that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be one way of doing it:

```
template<class... Args>
void log(uint8_t level, const char* fmt, Args&&... args) {
    char msg[128];
    int  msg_size = std::snprintf(msg, 128, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    callback->dosomething(level, msg); // some api
}
```

Note that I'm using `snprintf` instead of the `va_list` specific `vsnprintf`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GbvMb41sj)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use C++ variadic templates, there is very little use for C-style printf formatting (which is not type-safe).  You should fully embrace variadic templates (one of the main reasons variadic templates were invented was to get rid of the type-unsafe nature of the `printf`-style functions).

For example:

```cpp
void log_impl(std::ostream&) {}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void log_impl(std::ostream &os, const T &first_arg, const Args&... args) {
    os << first_arg;
    log_impl(os, args...);
}

template<typename ... Args>
void log(uint8_t level, const Args&... args) {
    std::ostringstream msg;
    log_impl(msg, args...);
    callback->dosomething(level, msg.str().c_str()); // some api
}
```

```cpp
log(level, "Hello ", "World", '!', " ", 12345);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/y8Rksb)

Or, in C++17 and later, you can use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to simplify the above code:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args>
void log(uint8_t level, const Args&... args) {
    std::ostringstream msg;
    (msg << ... << args);
    callback->dosomething(level, msg.str().c_str()); // some api
}
```

```cpp
log(level, "Hello ", "World", '!', " ", 12345);
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4vWTG9z3x)

But, that being said, if you absolutely need to use format strings, and you are using C++20 or later, then you should consider using [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (or the [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library) instead, eg:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args>
void log(uint8_t level, std::string_view fmt_str, Args&&... args) {
    std::string msg = std::vformat(fmt_str, std::make_format_args(args...));
    callback->dosomething(level, msg.c_str()); // some api
}
```

```cpp
log(level, "{} {}! {}", "Hello", "World", 12345);
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3j8z6jjd6)

Comment: In C++17 there's also the option to use fold expressions `((msg << args), ...);` instead of calling `log_impl`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, I have updated my answer with an example. The correct fold is `(msg << ... << args);` instead.

Comment: Yes, that unfolds nicer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried yours first and it doesn't compile, so I played around with it until I got something that did compile, using an [example from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. [Seems to work fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/458h3nEn9)

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I tried it earlier, exactly as you have shown, all I got was a bunch of syntax errors (and yes, I tried with C++17 and C++20). But now it works fine with the same code. Odd. Oh well.